# What are .onetoc2 files?

Tags: file-type, onenote

What are MS OneNote .onetoc2 files? I need to know if this important or just a useless file.

Comment: This question should be moved to superusers or some other stackexchange vertical as it is not related to programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a OneNote table of contents file.